# Produtos dos pedidos (Array)

Tags: javascript, react, mongodb, array-multidimensional

Bom dia, tenho as seguintes linhas de código para retornar uma listagem de pedidos com os respectivos produtos. **Produtos** é um objeto dentro de **pedidos** no BD.

```
{transactions.map((order) => {
  return <ul className="collection" key={order._id}>
    Pedido nº<strong> {order.order_number}</strong> -
Data: {order.created_at.substring(8, 10)}-{order.created_at.substring(5, 7)}-
{order.created_at.substring(0, 4)} -
Produtos: {order.line_items.length} -
Status: aguardando produtos para envio

<div>
      {JSON.stringify(order.line_items, ["id", "title"])}
    </div>
  </ul>
})}
```

E o resultado é a tela abaixo (filtrei um registro apenas pra ilustrar):

> Pedido nº 1003 - Data: 08-09-2020 - Produtos: 2 - Status: aguardando
> produtos para envio [{"id":5827489562779,"title":"Patinho De Banho
> Termômetro Munchkin - White Hot
> Ducky"},{"id":5827489595547,"title":"Quarto produto: Produto fora de
> estoque"}]

Porém, estou tentando mostrar apenas o ID do Produto e o nome (um por linha). Gostaria de saber onde estou errando. :(

Agradeço pela ajuda.

Comment: Qual o problema ? Como você queria que aparecesse para cada um dos items ?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer um map dentro deste outro

```
{transactions.map((order) => {
  return (<ul className="collection" key={order._id}>
    Pedido nº<strong> {order.order_number}</strong> -
    Data: {order.created_at.substring(8, 10)}-{order.created_at.substring(5, 7)}-
    {order.created_at.substring(0, 4)} -
    Produtos: {order.line_items.length} -
    Status: aguardando produtos para envio
    {order.line_items.map(item => {
        return <div>{item.id} - {item.title}</div>
    })}
  </ul>)
})}
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo, Gabriel. Obrigado!